# Windows XP bind Win+Q to open/focus Total Commander?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to bind <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> key to open Total Commander or if it is already running - focus on it?

Answer (score 1):

1. In total commander, you can set it to allow only a single copy `Configuration -> Options -> Operations -> Allow only a single copy ...`, so if anything tries to open TC it will only focus on it.
2. You can bind a key combination to any shortcut you have in the start menu, so you can bind `Ctrl+Alt+Q` to it (this is what windows does when you key in `Win+Q`).
   If you don't mind using extra software - maybe [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can help you (I never tried it, just found it on another post on this forum).